# SQL syntax error when using the nodejs mariadb controller to create an index while it works in datagrip

Tags: node.js, mariadb

I've been struggling to find my issue here:
I create some tables from  my node code with the [mariadb node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mariadb) with this line:
`dbConn.query(fs.readFileSync('<path to the sql file>').toString())` (`dbConn` comes from a `pool.getConnection()` where `pool` comes from a `mariadb.createPool(...)`)

However while doing so I receive a `SqlError: (conn=3, no: 1064, SQLState: 42000) You have an error in your SQL syntax`. The error also dump the sql string provided and it matches the file content.
Bust most importantly, I don't receive this error when I execute the exact same sql file against the exact same database with datagrip !

The file look like this :

```sql
create or replace table app.AuthenticatedUsers
(
    UserId varchar(255) not null comment 'email encodé',
    token  varchar(255) not null,
    salt   varchar(20)  not null,
    constraint primary key (UserId)
);

create or replace unique index AuthenticatedUsers_UserId_uindex
    on app.AuthenticatedUsers (UserId);
```

And the error happen on this command: `create or replace unique index AuthenticatedUsers_UserId_uindex on app.AuthenticatedUsers (UserId);`, and I get this error every time I try to create an index (unique or not, on integers too), from node only.

How do I get that to work in Node as well ?

Comment: The full text of the error message would normally say `near xxx` to give a hint. Looking at the SQL and testing on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/51ivffqR) suggests that `constraint` needs to be omitted. When stuck on a syntax error, peaking at [the manual](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-table/) can validate some assumptions made. Also syntax can be dependant on MariaDB version so include that in your question next time. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For security reasons MariaDB Server (and MariaDB Connectors) do not support execution of multiple statements by default.

To enable support of multi statement execution you have to specfiy an option when establishing the connection. For node.js it is [multipleStatements](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/nodejs-connection-options/#other-options).